# mAP graph during training doesn't show

Tags: neural-network, google-colaboratory, yolo, darknet

I use this command to train in colab

```
!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg darknet53.conv.74 -dont_show -map
```

and when I click on chart.png
all I see is this it doesn't show mAP
[image]

Answer (score 1):

after 1000 iteration it shows the mAP
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Alexey/Darknet, mAP is only calculated every 4 epochs (minimum 100 iterations, see [Code](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/f83231fa1db7e8ca7141700f5c45fe90b015778b/src/detector.c#L301-L302)). One has to change the code in order to update mAP at a different interval.